# The local variable n may not have been initialised & The local variable s may not have been initialised?. I am accepting them as user input

Tags: java.util.scanner

First I have declared n. I have accepted n from user. And then printing the value of it. the error comes.

```
public class Class {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String n;
        double s;
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Name:");
        if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            n=scan.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the salary:");
        if (scan.hasNextDouble()) {
            s=scan.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.println("Name is: "+n);
        //error: The local variable n may not have been initialised.
        System.out.println("Salary is: "+s);
        //error: The local variable s may not have been initialised.
        scan.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Set them to null when you declare them. It's complaining because the initialisation is within an if that may not execute.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the variables n,s :
 String n="";
    double s=0;